Can MuiOtpInput give auto focus?
I have a OTP verification page. I am using MuiOtpInput package from mui-one-time-password-input.
I want the cursor to land on the first input by default but I am not able to do so.
Is this even possible with MuiOtpInput ?
Here's the code:
    <Stack gap={1} >
      <Typography
        variant={'body2'}
        color={theme.palette.secondary.main}
      >Enter your 6 digit code</Typography>

      <MuiOtpInput
        value={otp}
        length={6}
        onChange={(value) => setOtp(value)}
        gap={1}
        validateChar={(value) => {
          return Boolean(value.match(/[0-9]/) && value.length === 1)
        }}
        TextFieldsProps={{
          inputProps: {
            style: {
              fontSize: '22px',
              padding: '10px 10px',
            }
          }
        }}
      />

      {otpError && <SelectHelperText selectHelperText={otpError} />}
    </Stack>

I tried to ask chatGPT, it was saying to add autofocus prop.
I have already tried it, nothing happened.

You should probably look at and/or ask on that project's GitHub issues: https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-otp-input/issues

@AKX Okay, asked there as well.
